# PHP change array structure and set status

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**PHP Code:**

```
foreach ($fetch_res as $res){

        echo '<pre>';print_r($res);
}
```

**Array generated:**

```
Array
(
    [USERID] => 13663
    [PROJID] => 999
    [ENTRYDATE] => 13-NOV-14
    [STARTDATE] => 01-NOV-14
    [ENDDATE] => 20-NOV-14
    [ACTIVE] => 123
    [ALLOCATION] => 456
)

Array
(
    [USERID] => 13664
    [PROJID] => 999
    [ENTRYDATE] => 13-NOV-14
    [STARTDATE] => 01-NOV-14
    [ENDDATE] => 20-NOV-14
    [ACTIVE] => 124
    [ALLOCATION] => 457
)
```

whereas following fields have respective ID's and status based on ID's

```
ALLOCATION - 456(Y) / DEALLOCAION - 457(N) 
ACTIVE - 123(Y) / INACTIVE - 124(N)
```

Using the above information, how can I generate below required array format

```
array("ProjId"=>999,
      "RS"=>array( //ALLOCATION ACTIVE
         0=>array("13663","N","Y")
         1=>array("13664","N","Y")
     )
);
```

`RS` is the resource `ID` where `N` and `Y` indicates the status.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array();
foreach ($fetch_res as $res){
    $data['ProjId'] = $res['PROJID'];
    $data['RS'][] = array($res['USERID'], ($res['ALLOCATION'] == 456) ? "Y" : "N", ($res['ALLOCATION'] == 123) ? "Y" : "N");
}
```

If you need it as string then -

```
$data['RS'][] = '"'.$res['USERID'].','. ($res['ALLOCATION'] == 456) ? "Y" : "N".','. ($res['ALLOCATION'] == 123) ? "Y" : "N".'"';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But instead of `[0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13663
                    [1] => N
                    [2] => N
                )
`, how can I change it to  `0=>array("13663","N","Y")` ?

Comment: I wonder, but it gives the same result as with previous code.

Comment: Why do you need it like this??

Comment: I need to insert the data in same format, bypassing the key's and show values in comma separated format.

Comment: then store it as `string`. why `array`??

Comment: my mistake..fixed it.

Comment: The output is `Array
(
    [ProjId] => 
    [RS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Y
            [1] => Y
            [2] => Y
            [3] => Y
            [4] => Y
            [5] => Y
            [6] => Y
            [7] => Y
        )

)`

Comment: you can check it now.

Comment: Your code works perfect for array format, but not for string format. I wonder.

Answer (score 1):

rough coding. you may refine with your style.

```
  foreach ($fetch_res as $res){
    if($res["ALLOCATION"] == "456")$allocation = "Y";
    else $allocation = "N";
    if($res["ACTIVE"] == "123")$active = "Y";
    else $active = "N";

    $result[$res["PROJID"]][] = array($res["USERID"],$allocation,$active));
  }
```